# Function App with Vnet integration and Private Endpoint -> Server Response: Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

i deployed a function app in our azure tenant. The function app is deployed in a dedicated subnet for private endpoint and in dedicated subnet with vnet integration.

We are trying to deploy from a vm with a devops agent installed(the vm have private endpoint) to test the configuration. If function is not configured with vnet integration and private endpoint, deploy works fine. If function is deployed under vnet integration and private endpoint i'm getting this message:

[image: I]

function is reacheble from internet also is in vnet integration and with provate endpoint(i configured access restriction also for our vpn).

The vm with devops agent is in the same vnet with nsg rule setup correctly.

In function app configuration i configured this parameter:

WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER - 168.63.129.16
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL - 1

as microsoft documentation(i tried without it when function was under vnet and private endpoint but i get same problem)

The command that i run is `func azure functionapp publish functionname`

Nsg rule are configure as follow:

INBOUND:

source vm subnet - destination function private endpoint subnet -> allow any

I forgot to setup something?

Any advice is really appreciated :)

Comment: How do you configure this private endpoint? Is there any link you followed in your steps?

Comment: @NancyXiong we have other things with private endpoint and vnet integration(app service). We followed microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have created a private endpoint for your Azure function in the same subnet that the VM deployed inside. The command `func azure functionapp publish functionname` required request over the Internet, the problem happened because you have configured access restriction in your Azure function, which blocking this access. You may add the VM subnet in the access restriction.

Comment: Hi, no the vm is in a different subnet.
The problem was that azure function cannot communicate with storage account(it is with private endpoint and selected network enabled with our vpn ip).

I had to add vnet integration subnet in selected network of storage account and deploy started to work. Is strange becouse in outbound i opened all ports to do test.

With storage account with all networks selected and private endpoint function works too, but i think it pass from internet and not internally.

So thanks for the helps, i hope this will be helpful for other people